# I am struggling with this .htaccess URL rewrite..?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have traffic coming to a WordPress site at https://www.example.com/?edd-listener=IPN

I am trying to rewrite this so that it actually loads https://www.example.com/paypal-ipn-handler.php

I tried this, but it's just loading the WP home page instead of my paypal-ipn-handler.

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule /?edd-listener=IPN /paypal-ipn-handler.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I can't figure out what adjustment I need to make..??

Any feedback on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match a query string but `RewriteRule` only matches URI. Insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)edd-listener=IPN(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /paypal-ipn-handler.php? [L,NC]

# remaining rewrite rules below this line
```

Note that this will not change URL in browser. If you need that use:

```sh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)edd-listener=IPN(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /paypal-ipn-handler.php? [L,NC,R=302]
```